# cordova ios build fails with phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-cli

i build an app using phonegap and trying to do a build as follows

```
Cordova ios build
```

it ends up with

```
VSKUMAR-mac:ios vskumar$ cordova build ios
Error: Source path does not exist: icon.png
```

my config.xml has an entry like

```
  <icon src="icon.png" />
```

And the /www folder does have the default phonegap's image with name icon.png

My versions are:

```
VSKUMAR-mac:ios vskumar$ cordova -version
6.5.0
VSKUMAR-mac:ios vskumar$ phonegap version

6.4.6
```

Comment: Your icon is missing. Fix that?

Comment: shouldnt that be added by default when i created the project? also how do i fix it?

Comment: It's a PNG file, so anything should work. You can create these in seconds with the built-in screenshot tool if you're really strapped. I'm not sure why it wasn't populated, but at least *try* plugging that hole.

Comment: it's all there. see my updated question

Comment: Are you sure that's the right place for it? Wherever it's looking there's no file with that name, so maybe it's looking somewhere else.

Comment: and how do i know where it is looking it for?

Comment: First stop: The documentation!

Comment: Please change your tags - this is not a PhoneGap Build question. Tag it as "phonegap" and you will get more responses.

Comment: done the change

Answer (score 1):

```
 <icon src="icon.png" />
```

comment this line in config.xml file. It will not reflect to your application.

Or else put the "icon.png" file in www folder.

It will solve your error.

Comment: did you check it ?